# Setting the Docker's container environnement (Env) via the docker remote api

Tags: docker

I'm using dockerode to manage docker by the remote api. Everything works fine except that I can't figure how to set the environnement when I create the container.

The docker doc doesn't give any information about the Env post parameter format.

I tried   {Env: ["foo=bar","fii:boo"], ... } {Env: {"foo":"bar","fii":"boo"}, ... } without success.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

The correct format is like:

```
"Env":["KEY=value", "ANOTHER=value"]
```

If it isn't working for you there is probably another issue there.